# Noise during QAudioOutput::setVolume()

Tags: c++, qt

The file plays good, but when I try to change the volume by moving a slider in GUI, I hear some rattle. Is this a bug or kind of bad implementation of QAudioOutput? I need to use only QAudioOutput and QMediaPlayer/etc is not allowed. My volume changing code: famous player such as mplayer this problem is also present. Is this is a real problem in lower implementing of setVolume? My code is:

```
void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
    audio->setVolume(value / 100.0);
}
```

I also found that in very

Comment: possible duplicate of [Noise after changing volume in QAudioOutput](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821706/noise-after-changing-volume-in-qaudiooutput)

Comment: Are you hearing zipper noise?  That is a slight but noticeable artifact that you will get if the gain is being changed without doing any per-sample fading.  If you can record a sample of the produced audio (e.g. using SoundFlower or some other audio-output-capture mechanism) and then view it in a program like Audacity, you can see the problem as a series of stair-step discontinuities in the waveform's volume.  The solution is to implement a per-sample fading mechanism so that the volume slopes off smoothly rather than abruptly over a single sample -- dunno if Qt is set up to support that, tho.